# Inverted Collectors.toMap to add to an ArrayList

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I would like to put the frequencies of the numbers in a `TreeMap` with the frequencies as the keys and the numbers that have that frequency in an `ArrayList`.

I have two problems:

1) I'm getting a "non-static methods cannot be referenced from a static context" error in the first parameter (AFAIK the stream references an object - what's going on?)

2) There are 4 parameters for Collectors.toMap() - it seems like parameter 4 requires initialization with a new TreeMap>, parameter 2 could be an ArrayList add() function and parameter 3 could be null (maybe). How is this done?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> array = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 8, 4, 2, 3);

        Map<Integer, Long> m = array.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(m);

        TreeMap<Long, List<Integer>> tm = m.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, ...));
```

At the moment I can't use see how to get from 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html to where I need to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost correct in your reasoning... Just that the 3-rd argument is where you merge your values for the same key - so you can't omit it.

```
 TreeMap<Long, List<Integer>> tm = m.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  Entry::getValue, 
                  x -> {
                      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                      list.add(x.getKey());
                      return list;
                  }, 
                  (left, right) -> {
                     left.addAll(right);
                     return left;
                  }, 
                  TreeMap::new));
```

Comment: I edited the Array.asList line since it distracts from the question at hand.

Comment: @JohnEstess excellent, I've edit the answer to remove that also

Comment: You can save a few lines by having as the second argument to `toMap` the following: `x -> new ArrayList<>(singletonList(x.getKey()))`.

Answer (score 7):

I think `Collectors.groupingBy` makes more sense than `Collectors.toMap` to achieve what you are looking for:

```
Map<Long, List<Integer>> tm = 
    m.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, // group the entries by the 
                                                         // value (the frequency)
                                    TreeMap::new, // generate a TreeMap
                                    Collectors.mapping (Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                                        Collectors.toList()))); // the
                                                         // value of the output TreeMap 
                                                         // should be a List of the 
                                                         // original keys
```

You can replace `Collectors.toList()` with `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` to make sure that the values of the output `Map` are `ArrayList`s (though the current implementation of `toList()` already results in `java.util.ArrayList` instances).

For your sample input, this produces the following `TreeMap`:

```
{1=[1, 3, 5, 6, 8], 2=[2], 3=[4]}
```

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use streams to create the inverted map. Instead, I would just do:

```
Map<Long, List<Integer>> tm = new TreeMap<>();
m.forEach((num, freq) -> tm.computeIfAbsent(freq, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(num));

System.out.println(tm); // {1=[1, 3, 5, 6, 8], 2=[2], 3=[4]}
```

As the code to create the inverted map is short, you could use `Collectors.collectingAndThen` to create both the frequencies and inverted map in one step:

```
TreeMap<Long, List<Integer>> invertedFrequenciesMap = array.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()),
        map -> {
            TreeMap<Long, List<Integer>> tm = new TreeMap<>();
            map.forEach((num, freq) ->
                    tm.computeIfAbsent(freq, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(num));
            return tm;
        }));
```

Comment: definitely +1 (wanted to show the same thing initially, but the OP asked about how to do with `toMap`...)

Comment: all of the answers above I have up-vote, so you have mine too. :)